# Does a scaled sum of square convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is this kind of function convex ?

$f\left( {{w_1},{w_2},..,{w_n}} \right) = {a_1}{\left\| {h_1^T{w_1}} \right\|^2} + {a_2}{\left\| {h_2^T{w_2}} \right\|^2} + .... + {a_n}{\left\| {h_n^T{w_n}} \right\|^2} + b$

where ${h_1},{h_2}...{h_n}$ are vector that contain real number.

Also, we have that ${a_1},{a_2},..,{a_n} > 0$ and $b>0$

My guess is it kinda is but I dont know how to proof it ?

Comment: Individually, each term is convex. The sum of convex functions is again convex. To see this, write the convexity inequality for each term then add all the inequalities.

Comment: I don't see where the "shifts" are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that
$$f_i(\omega_i) := a_i \Vert h_i^\intercal \omega_i \Vert^2$$
is convex for each $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$(proven easily by using properties of norms), it suffices to show, that a finite sum of convex functions is convex.

Let $g,h$ be convex functions. So we have for each $\tau \in (0,1)$, and for each $x,y$ in the domain of $g,h$ that
$$ (i) \quad g(\tau x + (1-\tau)y) \leq \tau g(x)+(1-\tau) g(y) $$
$$(ii) \quad h(\tau x + (1-\tau)y) \leq \tau h(x)+(1-\tau) h(y)$$
Adding the inequalities we get:
$$(g+h)(\tau x + (1-\tau y)) \leq \tau (g+h)(x) + (1-\tau) (g+h)(y) $$
Inductively it follows that finite sums of convex functions are convex.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In fact, have you noticed that if one includes all the $a_k$s into the norms which is possible because you assume them $>0$, and drop $b$ which is unimportant, i.e., if we work on :

$$f\left( {{w_1},{w_2},..,{w_n}} \right) = \left\| {h_1^T{w_1}} \right\|^2 + \left\| {h_2^T{w_2}} \right\|^2 + \cdots + \left\| {h_n^T{w_n}} \right\|^2$$

we can write $f$ in a compact way:

$$\underbrace{f\left( {{w_1},{w_2},..,{w_n}} \right)}_{f(W)}=\|diag(H^TW)\|^2\tag{1}$$

$H$, resp. $W$, being the matrix whose rows are the $h_k$s, resp. the $w_k$s, and "diag" is the "diagonal extraction operator".

Out of expression $(1)$, the proof of convexity is a matter of calculation on a matrix space, this time.

Comment: You haven't reacted to my way of expressing your issue. I have assumed that each $w_i$ is a vector. Is it the right interpretation ?

Comment: Could you answer my question ?

Comment: yes each of them is a vector